# Javac cannot access classes within libraries

Tags: java, bash, libraries, javac

I'm currently having trouble with compiling a project I'm working on.
I use some libraries, namely `lwjgl`, `slick` and `jorbis`. I've added them to my classpath and I am compiling with the following command

```
javac -g -classpath ".:./lib/lwjgl.jar:./lib/slick.jar:./lib/jorbis-0.0.17-2.jar" -d ./bin @files
```

The `files` file is simply a list of every class I'd like to compile.

The compiler then throws a  lot of errors like:

```
    foo\bar.java:25 cannot find symbol
    bar\foo.java:3  package does not exist
```

What's especially strange is that compilation worked on a previous project where I only used one library instead of multiple.

I use Sublime Text 3 and bash on Linux Mint to code / compile  my work (if that helps.)

All help is very welcome =]

[EDIT]:
I got the project to compile now.
I also tried to compile this on Windows (using git bash) and I get the same errors, but not on Linux anymore. I'll try to compile using a batch script on Windows, but at least I can compile it =]
Also works when I pack the finished project into a `.jar`.

Thanks y'all.

Comment: Post the `files`. This looks suspiciously like you're using a backslash as a path separator on Linux.

Comment: Your backslashes point to Windows, where the classpath needs `;`, not `:`.

Comment: @chrylis the `files` looks like this:

./src/levelbuilder/Level1.java
./src/levelbuilder/Level2.java
./src/levelbuilder/Level3.java
./src/levelbuilder/LevelBuilder.java
./src/slicktype/game/camera/Camera.java
./src/slicktype/game/entity/EnemyWord.java
./src/slicktype/game/entity/Entity.java
./src/slicktype/game/entity/Player.java
./src/slicktype/game/entity/PlayerState.java
...

Comment: @Harald   
Thanks, I changed my build script  I had and now it compiles.

Comment: For what it's worth, moving to Maven or Gradle will make your life a lot simpler.